# Google Earth Engine. How to get cloud cover score for each image in image collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloud-cover

I want to estimate cloud cover of each image in an image collection + would like to print out results for every image. I can see that cloud cover estimates are available for each image in their properties. But how to extract them to one table?

I am using this data:

```js
//Load data collection
var l7r = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE7_L1T")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 144))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 51));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this answer by Christoph in the Google Earth Engine Developers Forum ([https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers.)).

```js
var getCloudScores = function(img){
    //Get the cloud cover
    var value = ee.Image(img).get('CLOUD_COVER');
    return ee.Feature(null, {'score': value})
};

var results = landsat.map(getCloudScores);
print(Chart.feature.byFeature(results));
```

Or you can export data to drive:

```js
// Export data to drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: results, 
  description: 'File_Name',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```